# Response is always null after ajax-submit and bootsrap modal dialog doesn't close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, response, form-submit

**Java script for submitting form via AJAX and Web service**

```
$('#btnSignup').click(function(){ 
            var user = {"id": 10, "firstName": $('#firstName').val(), "lastName":     $('#lastName').val(), "age": 69, "freeText": "55555", "weight": 55};

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/testSoft/webresources/entity.user/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            //data: $("#register-form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(response) {
                alert('response: '+response);// This is always NULL?

            },
            error: function(data) {

                alert('addUser error: ');
            }
        });

    });
```

**Modal dialog that doesn't close after submitting**

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Sign Up</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="register-form" onsubmit="return false;"> 


                    <div class="register-form-block">
                        <input type="text" value='Your first name' name="firstName" id="firstName" onclick="this.value = ('')"/>
                    </div> 


                    <div class="register-form-block">
                        <input type="text" value='Your surname' name="lastName" id="lastName" onclick="this.value = ('')" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="register-form-block">
                        <input type="text" value='Username' name="username" id="username" onclick="this.value = ('')"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="register-form-block">
                        <input type="password" value='Password' name="password" id="password" onclick="this.value = ('')"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="register-form-block">
                        <input type="password" value='Password again' name="passwordagain" onclick="this.value = ('')"/>
                    </div>
                    <!--a href="javascript:doRegister();" class="register-button" id="btnAddUser" >Register</a-->
                    <br/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="btnSignup">Register</button>


                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
```

---

**Questions**

1) Why the response is always NULL? Request is adding data to DB successfully over web service.

2) Why the modal dialog doesn't close after submitting the form? I would like to get dialog closed and update one div and tell the user that sign up was ok.

3) How can I tell the server after errorless submit to go a different page, like www.google.com or another page in my web server in my app like thankYou.html?
I have got a FLAT learning curve in Jquery + Ajax stuff :( and this makes me crazy.

Thanks for helping!
Sami

Answer (score 0):

1) did you send anything back from the server side?

2) you probably have to close it manually with a function call.

3) window.location = 'http://google.com';

Comment: Thanks for answering! 1) Response body is empty.   2) I tried to find something like  success: function(response) {
                      $('#myModal').THERE IS nothing to close with? 3) So after successful submit I can just add the window.location..to success:

Comment: I ended up with hiding the whole div after success submit success: function(response) {$('#myModal').hide()}; and it seems to be working. Should there even be anything after successful POST? I have no idea...-----> THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION, the main windows is "grey/disabled" when using that